# Pandas: replace values strictly

Tags: pandas

In my data, there are a bunch of rows with the strange values of `" -   "` in string format which I want to replace.

When I run following code in jupyter:

```
df['Block Hours'][df['Block Hours'] == " -   "].count()
```

I get the output of 59 rows which I'm expecting.

However when I try to do following:

```
df['Block Hours'].str.replace(" -   ", "0.0").count()
```

I get more than 40,000 rows which is incorrect.

I'm on the latest version of pandas and also tried to make `regex=False` but the result is same.

```
df['Block Hours'].str.replace(" -   ", "0.0", regex=False).count()
```

**UPDATE:**

For anyone else coming here for similar kind of problem. Basically, my data type was Object and not string. I presumed that all datatype 'O' are basically string which is not true. So following code worked for me:

```
df['Block Hours'] = df['Block Hours'].astype(str).str.replace(" -   ", "0.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

`df['Block Hours'].str.replace(" -   ", "0.0")` gives you the whole column again, instead of just the ones with string replaced, so it will be different to what you expect. Try doing a filter on the column after replacing?

Comment: I did and it changed all the numbers into NaN

Comment: So basically it changed those 59 numbers to 0.0 but rest of them to NaN

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Is it a) replace b) count c) replace and count?

Comment: You are probably doing `df['Block Hours'] = df['Block Hours'][df['Block Hours'] == " -   "].str.replace(" -   ", "0.0")`, you should do `df['Block Hours'] = df['Block Hours'].str.replace(" -   ", "0.0")`. The former will assign NAN to any index that doesn't exist, the latter will make them unchanged (since they exist and are the same).

Comment: I've updated my question for the problem I had. You can have a look for your reference also. Thx

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
df['Block Hours'].replace(" -   ", "0.0", regex=True).count()
```

Comment: Didn't work either. I might have to have a deep look at my data. Thx for looking into this

Comment: I've updated my question for the solution I found. For your future reference.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.